# Why Swup.js does not handle relative links?

Tags: javascript, relative-url, swup

I'm testing [Swup.js](https://github.com/swup/swup)

As far as I see it doesn't work with relative links. Like this;

```html
<a href="./page.html">Go page</a>
```

[Screenshoot for link in DOM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KCY7e.png)

For this you need to enter the URL with the full path. But this may be undesirable. Relativity is used quite often, especially in designs with HTML content.

**It works when I do as follows.**

```html
<a href="//localhost/a/b/c/page.html">Go page</a>
```

This was not the case with **Turbolinks**. What is the reason of this? Do I need to make any adjustments? Thanks.

#### My index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>SWUP INDEX</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="">
  <script src="swup.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="1.css">
    <script src="1.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async defer></script>
</head>
<body>

  <div id="swup">

    <h1>INDEX</h1>
    <a href="/page.html">Go Page</a>
  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    var options = {
      LINK_SELECTOR: 'a',
      FORM_SELECTOR: 'form[data-swup-form]',
      animationSelector: '[class^="a-transition-"]',
      cache: true,
      pageClassPrefix: '',
      scroll: true,
      debugMode: true,
      preload: true,
      support: true,
      disableIE: false,
      skipPopStateHandling: function(event){
        if (event.state && event.state.source == "swup") {
          return false;
        }
        return true;
      },
    }
    var swup = new Swup(options);
  </script>


</body>
</html>
```

#### My page.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>SWUP PAGE</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="">
  <script src="swup.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="2.css">
    <script src="2.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async defer></script>
</head>
<body>

  <div id="swup">

    <h1>PAGE</h1>
    <a href="/index.html">Go Index</a>
  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    var options = {
      LINK_SELECTOR: 'a',
      FORM_SELECTOR: 'form[data-swup-form]',
      animationSelector: '[class^="a-transition-"]',
      cache: true,
      pageClassPrefix: '',
      scroll: true,
      debugMode: true,
      preload: true,
      support: true,
      disableIE: false,
      skipPopStateHandling: function(event){
        if (event.state && event.state.source == "swup") {
          return false;
        }
        return true;
      },
    }
    var swup = new Swup(options);
  </script>
  

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to insert that instead of (LINK_SELECTOR: 'a')

```
linkSelector: 'a[href^="' + window.location.origin +'"]:not([data-no-swup]), a[href^="/"]:not([data-no-swup])',
```